# issues with activex and aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, activex

I am building a small web app that will include an activex control. So I've built the activex control, it works fine when I use it in an html page. From some reason it won't work when used in an aspx page. The authority popup that offers me to include the control won't appear when it's in the aspx page. The problem occurs both when I try using the page in debug mode throguh visual studio, as well when typing the page's url and entering it through iis.

Any ideas?

Edit:
when I open the html file through iis the activex is again no recognized, it seems to work only when I open the file through file system

Comment: This would appear to be an issue of your IE settings not permitting ActiveX controls from the Intranet zone.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you compare the HTML from your test HTML page with the HTML generated by the ASPX page. The difference in behavior is likely to do with the difference in HTML.

Comment: wow, superfast responses, Thank you ! Same here to you David!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the ASPX page is being served from a different domain than the codebase for the ActiveX control.

Comment: I don't think I follow through, how do I check that? 
Some sort of an update, when I open the html file through iis the activex is again no recognized, it seems to work only when I open the file through file system. any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

ok, an evening after I found a solution:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic38890.htm

apparently the activex control must implement the IObjectSafety interface. Hope this helps!

Comment: Of course, that has nothing to do with whether it's a HTML page or an ASPX page, and depends entirely on what security zone the page appears within.